# Can I use a function with generic type inside a protocol extension of that same type?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a protocol :

```
protocol Repository {
    associatedtype Element
    func getAll() -> Single<[Element]>
}
```

And a function using this protocol in a generic way :

```
class Client {
    static func fetchCollection<T: Repository>(of params: T) -> Single<[T.Element]> {
        [...]
        return sendRequest(of: params)
            .flatMap({ (response: HTTPURLResponse, jsonData: Data) -> Single<[T.Element]> in
                [...]
         })
    }
}
```

It works just fine and is really convenient. The `getAll()` method I need looks like this in 2 examples :

```
class TypeARepository: Repository {
    typealias Element = TypeA

    func getAll() -> Single<[Element]> {
        return Client.fetchCollection(of: self)
    }
}

class TypeBRepository: Repository {
    typealias Element = TypeB

    func getAll() -> Single<[Element]> {
        return Client.fetchCollection(of: self)
    }
}
```

It works, but it's repetitive.

I would like to put the `getAll()` function inside a protocol extension because I have many objects implementing Repository and it would be cleaner to write it once.

But it does not work and I cannot find a way to fix it :

```
extension Repository {

    func getAll() -> Single<[Element]> {
        return Client.fetchCollection(of: self)
    }
}
```

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Here is the error (with my names, I simplified them above) :

[image]

Any ideas why ? And can it be fixed ?!

Comment: What's `client` and how would a _protocol_ know about it?

Comment: It could be confusing in first version, I edited it. Indeed `client` was a var that I simplified so I changed it to a more understandable `Client.`. now ; which refers to the function I put above.
It's not the problem here but it was a good comment, could have been that.

Comment: What is `sendRequest`? What requirements does it actually place on `params`? (It clearly can't call `getAll()` since that would be recursive.) Your code seems strangely circular, and I think you're imposing requirements that aren't needed. Also, does `getAll()` always look like this, or just in a couple of cases, but other types may have a different `getAll()`?

Comment: I tried to hack up something to reproduce your situation, and I couldn't. Can you look at this gist and adjust it to something closer to your real code and fails? Mine compiles. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/c0b9039f8b37319d44676f688c52468f

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Cocatrix/8660a34b28ccac77a9073b204b2ce933
I adjusted it and it compiles indeed, so I'm looking for a way to get closer to the real code but it's hard.

The Single I'm refering to is from the RxSwift library, it's hard to get close to.
Thanks for the gist anyway

Comment: Finally the problem was not associated to the Single, but to a nested generic that I didn't type correctly.
Using your gist helped me figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help

Working through gists helped me find a solution, it's a good way to work I'm happy to have learned that.

https://gist.github.com/Cocatrix/8660a34b28ccac77a9073b204b2ce933

Actually I simplified my code because the `Element` property itself had an associated property.

The only missing thing to compile was because I wrote `Single<Element>` instead of `Single<Element.Parsable>` in the original question.

The error displayed was not clear and I thought it was something similar to what matt discussed https://stackoverflow.com/a/68578593/7490668

It's resolved.

Comment: (I cannot put it as resolved until tomorrow)

Answer (score 2):

> but it's repetitive

I don't think you can do anything about that. They are actually completely different methods because the generic placeholder is resolved differently in each case. Thus you cannot "inject" any common implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I kind of thought the same, but couldn't explain it. I'm waiting a bit in case of a better idea

Comment: Yes, and there might _be_ a better idea, so you're right to wait. Part of the problem, of course, is that you showed totally fake code, which is never a big help to those who want to help.